# search form taking me to a second page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

[This is the form that I made from Clients_index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0tQx.png)I am using Elastic Search to find a client's name. I created a search for but as soon as you click search it takes me to a second page.
[It takes me here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ej2z.png)
Here is my view for Clients/_index.html.erb

```
<label for="existing-ads-client-name" class="big">CLIENT INFORMATION</label><br>
<div class="existing-ads-client-name">
    <%=form_tag clients_path,class: 'search-client', method: :get do |f| %>
        <div id="client-name">
            <%=text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>
        </div>
        <%=button_tag "Search", class: 'btn btn-default', name: nil %>
  <% end %> 
</div>
```

I am rendering it from AdGroups/index.html.haml

```
<div class="module existing-ads">
<div class="first-column">
<div class="field-content">
 =render 'clients/index'
```

And here is my Clients controller

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController

  def index
     @clients = Client.search((params[:name].present? ?  params[:name]: '*')).records
    render :partial => 'clients/index', locals: {clients: @clients}
  end
end
```

Any idea why?

Comment: It takes you to the page defined by the route `clients_path` because clicking the button submits the form. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @kcdragon I thought that was just going to stay in the same page since I am rendering the partial in another page, and it already creates a search button but then when you click it takes you to again another page and it say search again

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is the view you posted the index view for Clients (same as the path in the form)?

Comment: @kcdragon No , I have a view called AdGroups/index.html.haml and I am rendering it in that page =render 'clients/index' . So what I mean that when you click in the form , it takes you to another page again with a search bar.

Comment: @PamelaGuerrero, which view is this form a part of?

Comment: @PamelaGuerrero, you have the form in `clients/_index.html.erb`. And the form is submitted to `clients_path` which maps to the `index` action of `ClientsController`. In the `index action`, you're rendering `clients/_index` which displays a new form. What else do you expect to happen? If you want the results to be displayed in the same page as the form, you have to add a `remote:true` option in your form so that the form is submitted via AJAX and modify your action to render a `js` response.

Comment: @ArunKumar I changed to remote true, it's working better thanks